# Why do I get this error: "sonuc cannot be resolved"?

Tags: android

Why do I get this error: "sonuc cannot be resolved"?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle ben)
    {
        super.onCreate(ben);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final TextView sanuc=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.sonuc);
        final EditText say1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.sayi1);
        final EditText say2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.sayi1);

        Button topla=(Button)findViewById(R.id.topla);

        topla.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              //at the this place I did parsed to integer           
               sonuc.setText(Integer.parseInt(say1.getText().toString()) 
                                   + Integer.parseInt(say2.getText().toString()));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Which **sonuc** is not resolved?  "R.id.sonuc" or "final TextView sanuc"?

Answer (score 2):

Change sonuc.setText(...) to sanuc.setText(...)

You have different spellings for the xml id and the java variable name.